# Use persistent to allow closing a prompt (impromptu) in a specific state by clicking faded area.

Tags: javascript, jquery, impromptu

I am using impromptu to build something which uses tour like features on my website. I want the prompt to close if someone clicks in the faded area. According to what is mentioned in the documentation simply setting persistent to false should do this, but somehow this is not working. The prompt opens and position etc. is correct but it does not close when i click outside the prompt. I am able to close it only by clicking the close button. If someone knows how to solve this please let me know.

Below is what i have as the state in which the prompt should close by clicking anywhere in the fade area.

```
state1: {
    html: "sample text",
    persistent: false,
    buttons:{},
    position: {container: ".new", x:0, y:-75, width:250, arrow: 'bc'}
}
```

Comment: I was able to do this by adding the property as an option when calling the prompt. ie. $.prompt(states, {persistent: false}); If you know how I can add the property to only one state instead of all states please let me know.